# CORS issue React local client and AWS Lambda function

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, aws-lambda, cors, header

I'm trying to make a request from my localhost:3000 to a Lambda function that I developed

In my lambda function response I specified all needed headers to allow this

```
    return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps(result_object),
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',  # Use '*' for allowing any origin, or specify a domain to restrict access
        'Vary': 'Origin',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS',  # Optionally add other methods your API supports
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods',  # Optionally specify other headers your API accepts
    }
}
```

Also when I fetch the response say in Postman, I can see all the correct headers

[image]

But when I do the same via the react app from Chrome or Safari, I get these errors:

> Access to fetch at ... from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What also can I do to fix this?
Is there any issue in my headers format?

Comment: Code looks fine just need to enable CORS throu AWS Website, next time when you do setting thro Code use Stack so with code enabling will happen then dont need to go on website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing "You have to enable CORS in both Lambda and API Gateway as well." If it doesn't work, then try adding domain name directly something like below.

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://localhost:3000"
```

Example:

```
    return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps(result_object),
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost:3000',  # Use '*' for allowing any origin, or specify a domain to restrict access
        'Vary': 'Origin',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS',  # Optionally add other methods your API supports
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods',  # Optionally specify other headers your API accepts
    }
}
```

Please refer the below link for more details:
[Enabling CORS for a REST API resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

Comment: in question we see already added that `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` so from aws side enabling was required not code, you might want to edit answer

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the API Gateway,

so you have to configure CORS settings in both, your Lambda and API Gateway as well.

[image]